# Create vectors based on features of clustering in R

Tags: r

I have a the results of two clusterings and I would like to create vectors so that all features that belong to the cluster are listed in a vector.

The following dataframe results from a clustering algorithm. The columns "C" are the clusters from two different algorithms.

```
| A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 | C1 | C2 |
| -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- |
| 0  | 0  | 0  | 15 | 0  | 1  | 1  |
| 0  | 20 | 34 | 0  | 0  | 2  | 2  |
| 33 | 0  | 0  | 7  | 0  | 1  | 1  |
| 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 85 | 3  | 2  |
| 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 94 | 3  | 2  |
| 0  | 12 | 57 | 0  | 0  | 2  | 2  |
```

I want to create one vector for each cluster so that at the end I have

```
c11 = ['A1','A4']
c12 = ['A2','A3']
c13 = ['A5']

c21 = ['A1','A4']
c22 = ['A2','A3', 'A5']
```

EDIT:
To be more specific, the code should create a vector for each cluster in this way: If the cluster has a value different from 0 in any of the cluster specific rows for a feature, then add this feature to the vector.

In the first step for the second clustering the algorithm looks at cluster C21 (Rows 1 and 3) according to this rows the features A4 and A1 might be positive in instances of the cluster. In the second step the algorithm looks at the rows 2, 4, 5 and 6 for C22. There the values A2, A3 might be positive (according to the 2nd and 6th row) and the A5 as well (according to the 4th and 5th row)

EDIT2: The question was already solved but I still have a question in the special case that each instance would be clustered in multiple clusters and these are not disjunct. In this case the clusters are given as a string.

```
| A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 |   C  |
| -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | ---- |
| 0  | 30 | 0  | 15 | 0  | "1,2"|
| 0  | 20 | 34 | 0  | 0  |  "2" |
| 33 | 0  | 0  | 7  | 0  |  "1" |
| 28 | 0  | 0  | 0  | 85 | "3,1"|
| 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 94 |  "3" |
| 0  | 12 | 57 | 0  | 0  | "2,3"|

c1 = ['A2','A1','A4','A5']
c2 = ['A2','A4','A3']
c3 = ['A1','A5','A2','A3']
```

Comment: Where is the one for 3, 2 combination from C1, C2

Comment: At the end I only want 5 vectors. 3 for the first algorithm because there are 3 clusters and 2 for the second algorithm because there are only 2 clusters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `list` of column names for each row, where the value is not equal to 0, by looping across the row with `apply` and `MARGIN = 1`, Use the column 'C1', 'C2' to split the `list`, loop over the outer `list` and `unlist` the inner `list` elements, get the `unique` and `sort` it

```
l1 <- apply(df1[1:5] != 0, 1, FUN = function(x) 
       names(x)[x])
lst1 <-  lapply(split(l1, df1$C1), function(x) sort(unique(unlist(x))))

lst2 <- lapply(split(l1, df1$C2), function(x) sort(unique(unlist(x))))
```

-output

```
> lst1
$`1`
[1] "A1" "A4"

$`2`
[1] "A2" "A3"

$`3`
[1] "A5"

> lst2
$`1`
[1] "A1" "A4"

$`2`
[1] "A2" "A3" "A5"
```

Comment: That does not lead to the results I wanted. When I run the code I get ("A1","A3"), ("A2"), ("A4", "A5")

Comment: @ncnc_2020 the logic after the update is not clear.  I tried `lst1 <- setNames(apply(df1[1:5] != 0, 1, FUN = function(x) names(x)[x]), paste0("C", df1$C1, df1$C2))`, but how are you getting the 'A2', 'A3', "A5' in C22

Comment: The second clustering is the same as the first one only that c12 and c13 are only one cluster c22. So c22 should contain all features that c12 and c13 contain. Ill do again an update

Comment: your second solution is on the right way, but there you define a new vector for each row. I want a vector for each cluster

Comment: @ncnc_2020 tey the updated one

Comment: Hey @akrun, I have a harder challenge, what if each instance belongs to more than 1 role and these roles are not disjunct? If you are up for it go check the update :)

Comment: @ncnc_2020 can you please post as a new question

Comment: I just posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69396636/create-vectors-based-on-features-of-clustering-in-r-when-instance-belongs-to-mu

Comment: @ncnc_2020 please check the soulution posted

Comment: I can't see your answer anymore, the question was closed. Could you please post it here? @akrun